# How to output value of var when debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am new to Visual Studio and have a question related to debugging.

I set a debugging breakpoint which has led me to a line that I need for the XML object values.  In this case it just called objectToSend(see below).  If I highlight the line when debugging I can see the value pairs for the object but is there a way to easily copy the values?  I've tried to right click thinking there would be an option there but the "copy" just gets the current var not the whole object.

```
var data = ToXml(objectToSend);
```

Sorry for such and easy question, I'm trying to learn how to debug in VS.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance, I appreciate it very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print a variable and all of its members, you can use the `Immediate Window`. Just set your breakpoint and enter the name of the variable when the breakpoint is hit. For the following code:

```
var kv = new Dictionary<string, string>();
kv.Add("one", "1");
kv.Add("two", "2");
```

the `Immediate Window` will print the following text when entering `kv`:

```
kv
Count = 2
  [0]: {[one, 1]}
  [1]: {[two, 2]}
```